# Show imageView,button and textView when no listView

Tags: android, listview, count, baseadapter

In Activity A, there has a `listView`. `ImageView`, `textView` and `button` will be shown if list size is equal to 0, otherwise they will display.

[When no listView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5exn.png)

But they still display even the `istView` size is not equal to 0.

```
 List<SearchResults> search = new ArrayList();
 BaseAdapter adapter;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        addInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NoData);
        adapter=new BaseAdapter(getApplication(),search);

        getData(name, month);  // retrieve data from MySQL
        adapter.getCount();
        if (search.size() == 0) {
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            displayText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.e("SA", "null");
        } else {
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            addInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            displayText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

**BaseAdapter**

```
public class BaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchResults> {

    Context context;
    List<SearchResults> search;

    public BaseAdapter(Context context, List<SearchResults> search) {
        super(context, R.layout.retrieve_data, search);
        this.context = context;
        this.search = search;
    }

     public int getCount() {
        return search.size();
    }
```

The log display `null` although  there has list.

**activity_a**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView

        android:src="@mipmap/background_image"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Data"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_login"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NoData"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think part of your problem is setting `INVISIBLE` for view visibility rather than `GONE`. I believe you will have to set `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`.
The difference is INVISIBLE will make the view invisible but leave the layout the same. So there will just be an empty space on that screen where the button should be. But `GONE` will allow the parent view to act as if the view is not there. Meaning the layout params of the View will no longer be respected which I believe is what you want.

> INVISIBLE = make the view invisible but continues to respect its layout params
>
> GONE = makes the view invisible and disregards the layout params of that view.

Also, make sure that your "search" list is being populated by the time you are creating the adapter. It may be wise to remove that from the OnCreate function and into the onResume function of your activity.